# git push linked to the wrong/with two accounts

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, github-for-mac

I am using a Laptop that they handed down to me at my internship, when I go to push, it was pushing with a different account. Even though I signed in and got authenticated when I pushed. (I also removed keychain password from mac)
[image]

As you can see the 'first' is my account, the others even though I signed in and got authenticated are not my github account, but has the same username.

I tried this method of committing after looking around

```
git commit --author='name <email>' -m '...'
```

but this ended up causing this:
[image]

I then tried this command:

```
git config --global --unset-all user.name
```

And when I go to push it pushed with this, the person that owned the laptop originally...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `--global` argument. Try following the steps below:

Open Terminal.

```
git config --global user.email "email@example.com" 

git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Confirm that you have set the email address correctly in Git:

```
git config --global user.email

git config --global user.name
```

Add the email address to your GitHub account by setting your commit email address on GitHub, so that your commits are attributed to you and appear in your contributions graph.

Comment: I was sure i tried this before and it didnt work, but it works now, thank you so much. If i may add a follow up question. I am planning on using two different accounts, one personal and one for internship. If i want to change between the two, do i just rerun these commands each time? Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to set two users for one repo or for two different repos ??

Comment: for two different repos, one for my side projects and one for internship

Comment: For setting repo specific username and email just cd into the cloned repo and run the above commands without --global. This will set username and email for that repo only.

Comment: Maybe you can add another question and add an answer there so that it will help others too. Everyone does not read comments carefully.

Answer (score 0):

To edit the git config file:

- The 1st way, you can set the global config in `$user_home/.gitconfig`.
- And the 2nd way, you can also set the config in `.git/config` in the project.

Add:

```
[user]
    name = yourname
    email = youremail
```